# CMD+] indent and CMD+[ deindent

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have the following code to indent a tab.

```
$('#submit-content').keydown(function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9 || e.metaKey && keyCode == 221) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
        var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                            + "\t"
                            + $(this).val().substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again
        $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
        $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
        }
```

I want to alter this code to de-indent.

I tried `-"\t"` but it wont work as expected

Comment: `-"\t"` do you mean instead: `.replace('\\t', '')`?

Comment: @A.Wolff Basically I'm trying to go back a tab